# Online Stop Watch Using Pure Javascript and HTML and CSS ( No Flash!)

Tags: webapp-rec, javascript, flash, website

Is there an online stop watch that is constructed using pure Javascript, HTML and CSS, without using Flash?

There are a [couple of flash-based online stopwatch websites](http://www.online-stopwatch.com/), but since I don't prefer flash based websites, so I'm now looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CubeTimer](http://www.cubetimer.com/) is light and stupidly simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "online stopwatch javascript" came up with these for starters:

- http://general.arantius.com/online-stopwatch
- http://proft.50megs.com/stopwatch.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.timer-tab.com

But it doesn't support lap/mark and doesn't show the milliseconds.

**Disclosure:** I wrote this web app.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest http://ipadstopwatch.com, it's pure JavaScript, it has a large display, and as the name suggest it works specially well on the iPad. It has has a timer that play's a sound when it reaches 0, and it's really easy to use.